# Два независимых пайплайна в одном

Tags: c++, gstreamer

К примеру у меня есть два (или более) видео, которые мне нужно, например, послать в shared memory. Тобишь это вроде двух независимых, но синхронизированных пайплайна. Так вот, главный вопрос: могу ли я объеденить их в один? Тобишь итоговый пайплайн будет иметь два входа и два выхода, цепи линковки тоже не пересекаются друг с другом. Вообще я уже так и сделал (просто в цикле добавляю к пайплайну новые элементы и линкую их между собой), но не могу найти в доках инфы о том, можно ли так делать.

Comment: не вижу причин почему так нельзя делать. но задайся вопросом синхронизированны ли пайпы. что будет если чтение одного файла лаганет

Comment: @eri собственно, в этом и вопрос... Точнее он более широк: какие подводные камни сдесь можно ожидать?

Comment: Да единственное что если лаганет один элемент - упадут всё цепочки